# onbeforeunload is not getting called when I close a tab

Tags: javascript

I have a tab that pops-up in my web app so that the user can perform additional actions.

If the user closes the tab, I want it to call a function on the parent page.

So after looking through the Mozilla documentation, I did this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    console.log('refresh game list');
    if (opener && typeof opener.gameListReload === 'function') {
        opener.gameListReload();
        self.close();
    }
}
```

But when I test it, nothing happens.  When I close the tab, I don't see anything happen on the parent page and I don't see anything in the console.  Not even an error message.

Am I not using the onbeforeunload function correctly?

Comment: You must have interacted with the page prior to closing it for the event to trigger.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks, do you mean I shouldn't do anything on the tab before closing?

Comment: @blex oops yes, I didn't copy and paste I just wrote it out in my question.  I will fix that typo.

Comment: No, you must actually interact with the page that is in the tab before closing for the event to trigger. Scrolling and clicking are usually enough.